# Should my iOS delegate methods always be returned on the main thread?

Tags: ios, delegates, queue, grand-central-dispatch

This is a 'best practice' question I can't seem to find a good answer for online. I am creating a static library of code, which provides several delegate methods for progress feedback amongst other things.

The library manages it's own queues, so things like downloads aren't done on the main thread obviously, but my question is should I ensure my delegate methods are always called on the main thread or is it acceptable to call them from the queued threads I am using? and rely on the developer who's using the library to check he's on the main thread if he wants to do UI updates in my delegate methods?

Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it either way; you just need to document this well.

Some APIs will call you back on the main thread, some on the thread (or runloop) you used to start the work, and others don't make any guarantees at all. Some will even let you pass in a GCD queue that is used for all callbacks.

Remember the delegate/callback could block for a non-trivial amount of time, so if your API needs to resume work as soon as possible, you certainly want to dispatch to another thread or queue.

Having said all this, unless performance is critical to you or the users of your API, I would go with the most convenient for the developer which would be the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems that 'best practice' in this case really depends on the scenario.

Comment: It really depends. But I would recommend to always use an "internal private" queue for executing the client's blocks. This is the only reliable way to avoid accidentally dead locks by the user's code when it calls a dispatch_sync() somewhere in the block.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm using internal private queues within the library.

Answer (score 0):

When I made my own download manager I kept delegate method calling on the secondary thread that was running connection objects instances, but it was because I had a "controller" that was dispatching success blocks on the main thread. In my opinion depends on at which level you library is involved, if you think that most of times delegate will call a method with subroutines that involve UIKit objects, since they are not thread safe, I will choose to dispatch them on main thread. If you think that after the delegate the user of your library could make further elaboration on data I will choose to stay on another thread, but stating that clearly on documentation. There is another point: speed, depending on three priority a secondary thread could be really slow.
[EDIT]
In a download manager KVO or notification is a better way to handling connections, as stated by Quinn an Apple Engineer in a WWDC video.

Comment: Thanks for your comments... Firstly, Quinn is a legend! Secondly, the problem I have is that my library does far more than act as a download manager, infact the download manager is a component within the library. So I wanted to avoid using KVO / notifications for one aspect, and delegate methods for another... But otherwise yes, i would agree with you.

Comment: Yes "The Eskimo" is a super hero, he's really a nice guy, always explain stuffs.

Answer (score -3):

Obviously you have to call delegate methods in main thread, because if i am not wrong, your delegate methods will be passed to some delegate object (user's class).

suppose you are downloading data in a queue , when the data is downloaded you will call a delegate method by passing it to a certain object of user's class, so it has to be in main thread.

Comment: When you say 'obviously'... Why is it obvious? The delegate methods still get passed back to the delegate object properly even if they are not on the main thread, it just means that the user's class needs to ensure it's running on the main thread if it want's to update the UI? (FYI, It wasn't me who downvoted your answer!)

Comment: I meant if you left it for user, then it makes user to go through your library code to know that whether he should call on main thread or other.

Comment: although i am not genius but whatever my experience is , you should make users work easy with this library.(and i upvoted your question, i am also waiting for others answer, Good point you raised it).

Comment: Okay, thanks... So it sounds like it really is up to the level of documentation I provide, and that best practice is considered to make it easy for the developer who's implementing it, rather than there being any set rules to follow.